# How to generate SAS token in azure JS SDK, from app client, without using account key

Tags: azure, azure-storage

How to pre-sign Url in azure using javascript SDK with App registrations -  Application (client) ID, client secret (value), Tenant_id and also account name, container name, blob name.
I am not able to generate Container Level SAS token for giving temporary access to my files.

```
    const account = "accountName";
    const containerName = "containerName";
    const blobName = "blob";

    const credential = new ClientSecretCredential(
        "AZURE_TENANT_ID",
        "AZURE_CLIENT_ID",
        "AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET"
    );

    const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
        `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net`,
        credential
        );
    
    const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
    let blobs = containerClient.listBlobsFlat({includeMetadata: true}); // works ok 


    await credential.getToken(); // how to generate sas token for my container to sign url ?
```

I do not want to use the account key, and it seems `generateBlobSASQueryParameters` function works with account key.

Answer (score 1):

> A user delegation SAS offers superior security to a SAS that is signed with the storage account key. Microsoft recommends using a user delegation SAS when possible

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-user-delegation-sas-create-dotnet

The link has a .NET sample, but you could translate to javascript.

There are also some test cases here demonstrating the usage: get a user delegation key from `BlobServiceClient`, then pass the user delegation key to `generateBlobSASQueryParameters()`

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/d2730549e078571df008e929f19c07aaf8f9efd9/sdk/storage/storage-blob/test/node/sas.spec.ts#L992-L1004

Answer (score 1):

I have succeeded with the following steps.

Have to add `Storage Blob Delegator` and `Storage Blob Data Reader` roles to my application client from storage container IAM, and add the following code to upper one.

```
const userDelegationKey = await blobServiceClient.getUserDelegationKey(new Date(), new Date(new Date().valueOf() + 86400));
const containerSAS = generateBlobSASQueryParameters({
    containerName,
    permissions: ContainerSASPermissions.parse("r"),
    startsOn: new Date(),
    expiresOn: new Date(new Date().valueOf() + 86400),
    version: "2018-11-09"
 },
 userDelegationKey,
 account
).toString();
console.log(`${containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName).url}?${containerSAS}`);
```